# Service broker routes and DNS

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

Apologies for the long post but I've recently seen some strange behaviour with Service Broker when the routes it uses reference a DNS entry, and I am wondering if anyone has seen the same?

We have utilised Service Broker to send messages from multiple databases on Server A to a single database on Server B, which contain chosen data modifications.
Recently we wanted to upgrade the database on Server B from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012.

The steps we took were:-

1. Setup log shipping for the database on Server B to a new database on a new server (Server C).
2. Disable the queues in Service Broker on Server B so that the messages stack in the sys.transmission_queue on Server A.
3. Take a tail log backup of the database on Server B (with norecovery).
4. Apply the last log backup to the database on Server C, then recover that database.
5. Update the DNS entry used by the routes in Service Broker to point to Server C.
6. Ping the DNS entry on Server A to ensure that it is resolving to the new server, Server C.
7. Enable the queues on Server C so that the messages can be passed from Server A.

The problem that we had was the messages continued to stack in the sys.transmission_queue.

We investigated the problem but could not find an answer. No errors in the transmission_status column in the sys.transmission_queue table and SSB Diagnose didn't highlight any issues.

It was only when I added a linked server (as, I admit, a complete stab in the dark) using the DNS entry (which successfully connected to Server C) that the messages started flowing.

All I can think of was that SQL Server had cached the old DNS entry and it wasn't until I created the linked server that the old value was over-written by the new one.

I should point out that this process worked when testing, the only difference was that the routes were using FQDNs instead of DNS entries.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before? If so, how did you resolve the issue?

Any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Andrew

EDIT - Adding Service Broker tag

Comment: I assume Service Broker got re-enabled on the database on Server C at some point?

Comment: Yes, the restore that brought the database online had the  ENABLE_BROKER switch

Comment: Ostensibly, you might have tried running this from an elevated command-prompt on SERVER A:  `ipconfig /flushdns`  - however, the DNS entry may still be cached by SQL Server.